# Remove the layer information from Adobe PDF

Tags: windows-7, adobe-acrobat, autocad

I make lots of drawings in AutoCAD and convert them to PDF and pass it on to the client.

What I do not want the client to see in the drawings, is the different layer information that PDF is offering.

I'm using Adobe Acrobat 9 on Windows-7 so I will be able to edit the PDF files.
So far I have seen options in AutoCAD using which you can suppress the layer information from being passed from AutoCAD to PDF.

The concern is for the files (100's of them) that have already been converted into PDF format. Is there a way to remove layer information from them?

Answer (score 1):

This may be a bit late.

You can change the settings before printing to tell ACAD not to include layer information.
Go to  Plot, Click properties for the PDF printer you use. (I use DWG to PDF)
Click custom Properties, The custom properties at the bottom of the Tab.
Then  Additional output settings untick "Include Layer information"
I also tick Capture all Fonts to avoid any compatability issues, but this may increase the file size slightly.

Brian

Comment: Welcome! Late isn't a problem at all -- the goal of Stack Exchange sites such as Super User isn't just to help the person who originally asked the question but also to help anyone else who might have the same problem in the future.

Comment: Appreciate your response. I had figured this out. I wanted to know, if something could be done to the PDFs that I have already created

Answer (score 0):

Often when converting files from Acad, Solidworks or other graphical complex software the PDF file is loaded with graphical (compressed) data without the required graphical enhancement complexity of the following software’s. this creates a file that is practically not access able on regular computers ands requires very high-end computers with graphical cards lots of ram memory and a H/HQ CPU.

my solution is simple.
open the "slow opening file" and print it as "Microsoft print to PDF" This way you remove the access data and "down scale" your pdf file.